# Difference between 'café' and 'cafeteria'

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference

Is there any differences between '***café***' and '***cafeteria***'?

When can we use "café"?

What is the difference between these two words?

Are they the same or not?

Comment: I can't write an answer right now, but a cafe is generally a coffee shop, like a separate building, and a cafeteria is a place in a building where people go to eat.

Comment: @Mithrandir Aha! Thanks.But i need more explanation!!

Comment: @IceGirl, have you tried looking in a dictionary? http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cafe?q=caf%C3%A9 http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cafeteria

Comment: Microsoft calls its cafeterias cafés.

Answer (score 1):

A cafeteria and a café are not the same thing.

What is a cafeteria?

> A cafeteria is a type of food service location in which there is little or no waiting staff table service, whether a restaurant or within an institution such as a large office building or school; a school dining location is also referred to as a dining hall or canteen (in British English). Cafeterias are different from coffeehouses, despite being the Spanish translation of the English term. - [Cafeteria (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cafeteria)

What is a café?

> A coffeehouse, coffee shop or café (sometimes spelled cafe) is an establishment which primarily serves hot coffee, related coffee beverages (e.g., café latte, cappuccino, espresso), tea and other hot beverages. Some coffeehouses also serve cold beverages such as iced coffee and iced tea. Many cafés also serve some type of food, such as light snacks, muffins or pastries. Coffeehouses range from owner-operated small businesses to large multinational corporations. - [Coffeehouse (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffeehouse)

Some Cafés in Europe also offer some wine or beer on their menus.